# How to create a X509 certificate in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, cryptography, x509certificate, x509

i have already generated public and private keys

```
Uint8List generatePrivateKey(String input1, String input2) {
    // Concatenate the inputs to create the seed
    String seed = input1 + input2;

    // Create a SHA-256 digest of the seed
    Digest sha256Digest = SHA256Digest();
    Uint8List seedBytes = Uint8List.fromList(seed.codeUnits);
    Uint8List digest = sha256Digest.process(seedBytes);

    // Create an ECC private key using the secp256k1 curve
    ECCurve_secp256k1 curve = ECCurve_secp256k1();
    ECPrivateKey privateKey =
        ECPrivateKey(BigInt.parse(hex.encode(digest), radix: 16), curve);

    // Make sure the private key is within the valid range for the curve
    BigInt n = curve.n;
    BigInt privateKeyInt = privateKey.d!;
    privateKeyInt = privateKeyInt % n;

    String privateKeyHex = privateKeyInt.toRadixString(16).padLeft(64, '0');
    Uint8List privateKeyBytes = Uint8List.fromList(hex.decode(privateKeyHex));

    return privateKeyBytes;
  }

  ECPublicKey generatePublicKey(Uint8List privateKeyBytes) {
    ECCurve_secp256k1 curve = ECCurve_secp256k1();
    ECPrivateKey privateKey = ECPrivateKey(
        BigInt.parse(hex.encode(privateKeyBytes), radix: 16), curve);

    ECPoint? publicKeyPoint = curve.G * privateKey.d!;
    return ECPublicKey(publicKeyPoint, curve);
  }
```

This is how I have generated the keys I am using pointycastle library, now I want to create a X509 certificate.

I have tried X509 library, dart:io, cryptography library.for rg

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:asn1lib/asn1lib.dart';
import 'package:cryptography/cryptography.dart';
Future<X509Certificate> generateSelfSignedCertificate(Uint8List privateKeyBytes,final publicKey) async {
  // final publicKey = generatePublicKey(privateKeyBytes);

  final certificate = X509Certificate(
    subject: X509DistinguishedName(commonName: 'Self-Signed'),
    issuer: X509DistinguishedName(commonName: 'Self-Signed'),
   ` serialNumber: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
    validity: X509Validity(
      notBefore: DateTime.now(),
      notAfter: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 365)),
    ),
    subjectPublicKey: await publicKey.extractRawSubjectPublicKey(),
    issuerPrivateKey: privateKeyBytes,
  );

  return certificate;
}
```

i am getting error on `X509DistinguishedName` that it is not defined

Answer (score 1):

In order to generate a certificate the process is :

1. Prepare a certificate signing request (CSR) containing the infos you want to put inside the certificate (the Subject DN, the public key, the validity period, the extensions, etc). The CSR is signed with the private key matching the enclosed public key in order to prove it has been created by the key owner (called *Proof of Possession*)
2. Sign the CSR with a private key to make a X509 certificate

When the certificate is self signed, the private key used to sign the certificate matches the public key of the certificate.

If you just want to generate a self-signed certificate, it is possible to use the [basic_utils](https://pub.dev/packages/basic_utils) package which provides CryptoUtils and

```
String generateSelfSignedCertificate() {
  var pair = CryptoUtils.generateEcKeyPair();
  var privKey = pair.privateKey as ECPrivateKey;
  var pubKey = pair.publicKey as ECPublicKey;
  var dn = {
    'CN': 'Self-Signed',
  };
  var csr = X509Utils.generateEccCsrPem(dn, privKey, pubKey);

  var x509PEM = X509Utils.generateSelfSignedCertificate(
    privKey,
    csr,
    365,
  );
  return x509PEM;
}
```

The package does not seem to provide a generic certificate signing feature but it is possible to write it by looking at the [`generateSelfSignedCertificate` code](https://github.com/Ephenodrom/Dart-Basic-Utils/blob/master/lib/src/X509Utils.dart#L296)